# Trying to get GridLines to show in Access ListBox

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-access-2013

I have a listbox on a form in msaccess and want to show the gridlines, but they won't show up for me.  I've set the style and color for top and bottom gridlines but nothing shows when the form is open.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a form with a *layout grid*.

These properties add a line outside the listbox when this i contained in the grid. Here a *dash line* is specified for the top gridline. The blue lines are the border of the listbox itself:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I'm actually looking for horizontal lines (or, preferably, alternating white and grey backgrounds to the line) for each list item.  Can I do this with the built in list box?

Comment: No. Use a subform in _datasheetview_.

Comment: I figured as much.  I've used that before.  I doesn't look quite as tidy (in my opinion) but I can manage with it.  Thanks for your help.